# Can an asymptote be a tangent line?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Consider [this function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO81g.png) and its horizontal asymptote. Can the asymptote (in blue) also be considered a tangent line to the curve (in red)? The slope of the curve definitely approaches zero as $x$ approaches $\pm\infty$, but does that mean that a horizontal tangent line exists? It isn't possible to find a point of tangency, so I'm not sure if it counts.

Comment: Do you consider $\pm\infty$ to be a member of the reals?

Comment: @AlexS  No. For the function of question though, when I use implicit differentiation and set the derivative equal to zero, I get $y = 1$ as a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asymptotic approach is not considered a form of tangency.  However, we can construct curves that are asymptotic and tangent to the same line, like the line $y=0$ with respect to the curve $y=(x^2)/(1+x^4)$.

Answer (score 1):

In projective geometry, if we allow a point at infinity $\{\infty\}$, then one can claim the asymptote is tangent at $\infty$.

In standard Euclidean geometry, no horizontal tangent line exists.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space for the definition and introductory discussion.